# Using local system as ssh client and server

Tags: linux, ssh

I am using local system to learn ssh and what I am trying to do is execute a command on the remote server.
I have ssh server running on terminal1 and client on terminal2.
I used the following command on terminal2:

```
ssh user1@127.0.0.1 echo Display this.
```

but it echoes on terminal2. How would I know if the command actually worked if it's not displaying in terminal1?
Thank you.

Comment: *Using my own system*...your system is failing you!...http://askubuntu.com/questions/220621/alternative-to-wall-talk-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked correctly. It ssh'd into the server, executed the command, and returned the stdout of that command back to you.

SSH gains access to the server, but not necessarily any TTY's active on it. You would have to jump through some hoops to send text to a specific TTY, such as your Terminal1.

A better test would be:

```
ssh user1@127.0.0.1 'touch ~/testfile'
```

Then you can check on your server (which is localhost) to see if `testfile` was created in your `user1` home folder. If it did, then the connection and the command succeeded.

Comment: terminal1 says it is not a tty when passed `tty` from terminal2. I get why it says so, but is there a way to differentiate between the two?

Comment: That might be a good new question on here. I've never really tried sending to a seperate tty, so I probably won't be much help. [The link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220621/alternative-to-wall-talk-write) that @hackerman suggested above may help with that. I would try getting that working first outside of SSH on the same machine, before adding the overhead of ssh into the equation though.